# Email validation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, email, column, validation

We have a column of type "E-Mail" and we'd like to attach validation to it so it conforms to the normal regular expression email validations at a specific domain. Is this possible without writing a web part in Visual Studio? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This codeplex project allows you to add regular expression validation to fields

[Codeplex - SharePoint Custom Field Type - Regular Expressions](http://spregex.codeplex.com/)

Be very careful trying to validate email addresses using RegEx though (either through this tool or javascript) - its seems like a ideal candidate for regex until you get into the details and there are a lot of samples out there that are wrong.

For example :-

- Hardly any one will accept apostrophes in the email - yes o'callahan@tld.com is valid!
- Many of the example out there will not accept bob@tate.museum [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) and this will only become unmanageable now that the [restrictions on creating TLD's have been relaxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain).

Answer (score 2):

Other methods you can use:

- Create a validation formula in the List Settings / Validation Settings.
- Add some script to your forms to validate on the blur event or in the PreSaveAction

I prefer using script on the blur event because I can give immediate feedback to the user, as they are used to on other modern Web sites.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I should have mentioned one other option, which is probably more the party line: a custom field type. I still like the script option better from a UX perspective.

Comment: You could actually combine the two - a custom field type that uses javascript to do the validation client side as well as server side.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/validate-a-sharepoint-list-column-with-regular-expression/) gives you two different options. One that involves inserting a hidden web part in the EditForm for the list, and using JQuery to do the actual RegEx validation. Another option is to go with the third-party tool Christian refers to in the article.

Comment: Yes, of course - as Marc points out below - the built-in validation. I just tried it; a validation formula like =SEARCH(".",[Email],(SEARCH("@",[Email],1))+2)>0 will check for the "@" and the ".". However, in my setup, my custom error message when the validation fails does not display. SP just displays a standard validation message. Not sure why yet. So UX-wise, this is not the best, so far.